How can I set voltage on N6792A power supplies modular?
I have two N6792A modular installed in N6702C mainframe. It keeps showing "Unr" unregulated when meter is on.

Can you ask the manufacturer for help? Many supplies won't work well without a minimal load. Perhaps that's what the problem is. Attach a reasonable resistive load to them and see if that maybe helps.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Thanks for your input. I just want to give back to community what I found. Yes you were right. It needs a proper setup such as load and it has modes to choose.
